# Delete objects from Gitlab repository within a certain date range

Tags: gitlab, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-filter-repo

I have to remove a number of files from a git repo on [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/) that are tracked with [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.com/). They were automatically updated in a nightly CI build over a number of weeks and I quickly ran out of storage space.

I have followed the [original documentation on cleaning up a gitlab repo](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html), but found it to not lower the used storage space. I probably did something wrong in my attempt to not delete this file across the **entire history**, but just **within a certain date range**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps using the [bfg repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) instead of [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) ended up working:

(**Note:** `git rev-list` is your friend! This was the main thing that helped me filter out exactly which objects to delete from history. It's worth looking at its [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)!)

1. Follow the [original docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html) until step `6.`

- Generate a fresh export from the project and download it.
- Decompress the backup using tar: `tar xzf project-backup.tar.gz`
- Clone a fresh copy of the repository from the bundle using --bare and --mirror options: `git clone --bare --mirror /path/to/project.bundle`
- Go to the `project.git` directory
- Because cloning from a bundle file sets the origin remote to the local bundle file, change it to the URL of your repository:  `git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project_name>.git`

2. Download the bfg repo cleaner `.jar` file from [here](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)
3. Find the object IDs for the file path to delete in certain parts of the history. The easiest way for me was to simply filter by dates (replacing `<YYYY-MM-DD>` with the start/end dates between which to scan the git repository for the file marked as `<file path in repo>`):

   ```
   git rev-list --all --objects --since <YYYY-MM-DD> --before <YYYY-MM-DD> | grep <file path in repo> > object_ids_to_delete.txt
   ```
4. The file will contain a list of lines like `<Object ID> <file path>`, so just remove all instances of  `<file path>`
5. Run `bfg` on the repo with the given set of object IDs: `java -jar bfg.jar -bi ./object_ids_to_delete.txt ./project.git`
6. Go to the repo folder: `cd ./project.git`
7. Update the reflog: `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` (see [bfg docs](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage))
8. Continue with the remaining steps from the gitlab docs:

- To allow you to force push the changes you need to unset the mirror flag: `git config --unset remote.origin.mirror`
- `git push origin --force 'refs/heads/*'`
- (the rest of the `push`-steps weren't necessary for me...)

9. Wait 30 minutes.
10. Locate the commit map file that `bfg` generates: it should be in `./project.git.bfg-report/<date>/<timestamp>/object-id-map.old-new.txt`
11. Upload it in the "Repository Cleanup" part of the project settings, [as described in the next step in the gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#repository-cleanup)
12. Wait some more...
13. Success!